# Postman extension get a response, but my jquery request not

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, postman, same-origin-policy

I make a GET request using Postman extension and obtain a response, but if I make the same request using jQuery I receive a typical error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.rfen.es/publicacion/ranking/resultsBySwimmer.asp?l=020039535&t=&p=0&e=50L-I.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Why does this happen?

My javascript code is simple:

```
function getTiempo (dni, piscina, prueba) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.rfen.es/publicacion/ranking/resultsBySwimmer.asp?l="+dni+"&t=&p="+piscina+"&e="+prueba
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```

The Postman extension is not on the same domain either, why does it get a response?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/3370595

Comment: Your answer can be found below. Its a problem with data types i think.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/20035319#20035319

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to help future fellows seeking for this specific question: **Why POSTMAN works and my jQuery don't!**

The answer is quite simple, actually: Chrome Extensions are allowed to do so!

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: funny fact #1: If you open the debug console on same POSTMAN tab, you will be able to execute your $.ajax, the request will work, because you are in the chrome extension "context"!!